# spring sso with docker images

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker

I am following [this tutorial](https://shekhargulati.com/2018/02/15/single-sign-on-in-spring-boot-applications-with-spring-security-oauth/) and it works perfectly, it is single sign on application, then I tried to build a docker image for each service and expose ports they are using but when I login the app1 service this response:

```
    Whitelabel Error Page
    This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

    Sun Feb 10 11:11:54 GMT 2019
    There was an unexpected error (type=Unauthorized, status=401).
    Authentication Failed: Could not obtain access token
```

Maybe both docker images are not communicating each other, because if I launch this spring-boot applications without docker they are working perfectly.

In [that codes](https://github.com/shekhargulati/spring-boot-sso) only I have introduced a mvn plugin to buid a docker image for each project (sso-server,app1,app2):

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <repository>MYREPO/project</repository>
                        <tag>${project.version}</tag>
                        <buildArgs>
                            <JAR_FILE>target/${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
                        </buildArgs>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>default</id>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>build</goal>
                                <goal>push</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

I tried name each image (-n) and link each (--link) other but it does not work.

Some advice?

Comment: Have you tried with docker-compose?

Comment: Could you share us your application.yml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All URI in the [application.yml](https://github.com/shekhargulati/spring-boot-sso/blob/master/app1/src/main/resources/application.yml) file are defined for going to `localhost`. If you want to go one container to another, you can use the IP address of the host or the docker bridge address (default address is `172.17.0.1`).

Comment: You can complete your answer by including some explanation about how to do

Comment: I understand, but both images must have this address? or I can define a ip address for each? I am trying doing this without docker compose because the second part is add kubernetes

Comment: Replacing localhost to host IP address or 172.17.0.1 in application.yml file of apps may resolve your problem.

Comment: It works ! thanks @aburakc . Now my goal is create a kubernetes-pod with each image, will I need change this ip-address? or must I specify a IP for each pod ?